# How to add a button which prints a pdf document on my webpage?

Tags: html

I want to add a button to my website which will allow the user to print an attached PDF document, which is stored locally on the website server.

How can i do this?

Comment: **How can i do this?** Ans: By doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) There are so many answers on this question. I am sure you will be able to find the best one suited for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can this scenario from print.js.
That's very simple.
Please check [here](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) this page and download materials and later follow my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/print.min.css" type="text/javascript"/>
<title>TEST PRINT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="print my pdf directly ('media/arg.pdf')">
    Print PDF
 </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manage to print a PDF file just like that. This is an action that the user has to perform when opening the PDF file.

Once the PDF file is opened you also cannot force print.

The only suggestion I would give you here is just to add a link to that PDF and the link text could be something like:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/pdf/uploaded.pdf">Click to open PDF and print it</a>`